# summations $p$, $q$ For positive real numbers $ a_1, a_2,a_3....., a_{100}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For positive real numbers $ a_1, a_2,a_3....., a_{100}$, let $$p=\sum_{i=1}^{100} a_i $$

$$q=\sum_{1\le i \lt j \le 100} a_ia_j $$
Then

1. $ q=p^2/2$
2. $ q^2\ge p^2/2$
3. $ q\lt p^2/2$
4. None of these

I need suggestions in interpreting $q$.
thanks

Comment: You should try this with $a_1, a_2$ and then $a_1\ldots a_3$ instead of $a_1\ldots a_{100}$ as a warmup. You might be able to see a pattern.

Comment: In q,  j shoud be more that i, but how much more? If i is 1 now j could be 2 , 3 anything less than 100. So how will q look like

Comment: Compare $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^2 a_i$ with $\displaystyle \sum_{1\le i<j\le 2} a_ia_j$. Then replace $2$ with $3$ and see if you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Note that we have
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^2 - 2\sum_{i\neq j}^n a_i a_j = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 \geq 0$$
In fact, if $a_k$'s are positive, we then have
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^2 - 2\sum_{i\neq j}^n a_i a_j = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 > 0$$
We hence have
$$p^2-2q > 0$$

Answer (score 0):

For instance, take $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 2$. Then $p = 3$ and $q=2$. Now, $p^2/2 = 4.5$ and $q^2 = 4.$ Rest is easy to follow. You can also, take all the $a_i$'s as $1$ and check for $n=100$.